# Whatsapp < last seen at...>

Tags: whatsapp

I've been searching for an app that shows who viewed your Whatsapp profile. I didn't find one, is there such an app that tells you who saw your Whatsapp < *last seen at...*> ??

Answer (score 1):

#### When did someone last see your profile?

This functionality is built in to WhatsApp itself so you don't need another app to get this information.

#### Who viewed your profile?

By `viewing your profile`, I assume you mean someone long tapped on your name and then clicked `View profile`.

No- there is no app out there on any platform (not just Windows Phone) that provides this functionality.

[You are not the only one- there is someone else who also wants this functionality.](http://www.freelancer.com/projects/Mobile-Phone-Objective-C/Who-Viewed-Whatsapp-Profile.html) I wouldn't hold my breath though- I have my doubts about if even WhatsApp has this data.